# Probability in the logistics equation?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, mathematical-physics

### Assumptions for reaching the [logistic map equation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ovJcsL7vyrk)

Conjecture $1$: Assumption for a species genetically/mimetically/etc there "life" prefers the state found in the maximum population for a species.

Conjecture $2$: All members of a species influence each other and each influence and member is unique

Conjecture $3$: There is only one dominant influence carried on by an individual required which must extend

### Population Dynamics

Let the total population of the $i$'th generation be $T_i$ and the maximum of the distribution be $x_{max}$.

Let's presume we do not know which generation we are in ($i$ or $i+1$):

Probability of belonging to the $i$'th generation = $ \frac{T_{i}}{T_i + T_{i+1}}$

Probability of an individual to influencing a generation = $ \frac{1}{T_i + T_{i+1}}$

Probability of finding the maximum of the distribution = $ 1/ x_{max}$

Consider,

$$ \underbrace{\frac{T_{i}}{T_i + T_{i+1}} \times \frac{1}{T_i + T_{i+1}}}_{\text{probability of individual influencing current generation}}$$

and,
$$ \underbrace{\frac{T_{i}}{T_i + T_{i+1}} \times    \frac{T_{i}}{T_i + T_{i+1}}}_{\text{probability of all members influencing each other}} \times \underbrace{\frac{1}{x_{max}}}_{\text{probability of finding global distribution maxima}}$$

and,

$$ \underbrace{\frac{T_{i+1}}{T_i + T_{i+1}} \times \frac{1}{T_i + T_{i+1}}}_{\text{probability of individual influencing future generation}}$$

For continuity of the influence from one generation to another we have:

$$ \frac{1}{4} \times \frac{T_{i+1}}{T_i + T_{i+1}} \times \frac{1}{T_i + T_{i+1}} +  \frac{T_{i}}{T_i + T_{i+1}} \times \frac{T_{i}}{T_i + T_{i+1}}  \times \frac{1}{x_{max}} =  \frac{T_{i}}{T_i + T_{i+1}} \times (  \frac{1}{T_i + T_{i+1}})$$

We introduce the parameter $a$ with $T_i$ the total population in the i'th iteration. Hence:

$$x_i = T_i/(a/4)$$

With:

$$x_{max} = a/4$$

Upon simplyfication:

$$  T_{i+1} =   4 T_i \times (1-  \frac{T_i}{x_{max}})$$

We arrive upon the logistics equation which describes the population dynamics equation:

$$x_{i+1} = a x_i (1 - x_i) $$

### Question

What is the [correct interpretation of probability in this situation](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/probability-interpret/#MaiInt)? The logistic's equation has many uses in many systems does the interpretation change?

Comment: Am I correct in thinking of this as an equation of continuity of some sort?